# Prove that if $X$ is a reflexive Banach space and $Y\subset X^*$ is closed and separates the points of $X$, then $Y=X^*$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Prove that if $X$ is a reflexive Banach space and $Y\subset X^*$ is closed and separates the points of $X$, then $Y=X^*$.

I tried a few things, but nothing worked.  Firstly, I concidered that there is a $g\in X^*\setminus Y$ and since $X=X^{**}$, for $f\in Y$ there is a $x\in X$ such that $f(x)\neq g(x)$ but it didn't help me much.

Then I tried to use the fact that $Y$ separates the points of $X$ somehow, but with no success. I wanted to show that $B_{X^*}\subset Y$ but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $Y$ is closed, if $y\ne X^*$ then Hahn-Banach shows that there exists $\lambda\in X^{**}$ with $\lambda\ne0$ but $\lambda y=0$ for every $y\in Y$. Since $X$ is reflexive this shows that $Y$ does not separate points of $X$.